# Whatsapp Cloud - Product Catalog - Batch APIs not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whatsapp, facebook-marketing-api, product-catalog

We need to create, update or delete product(s) from our catalog.

For doing this programatically we are following Meta's Product Catalog Batch API documentation in which there is an endpoint mentioned as "<product_catalog_id>/batch". We are trying to make request at this endpoint by passing the payload as mentioned in the official documentation.

But I am getting "403 forbidden" error every time. On digging deeper I found that the access token which is making this API call must have 2 permission i.e. "catalog_management" and "business_management".

I have checked the access permission for my access token and it indeed has there 2 permissions.

Can anybody please help here?

I am attaching some links below, which I am using to make the batch API calls for product catalogs.

Using this link to understand the API structure = https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/catalog-batch/guides/send-item-updates/

Using this link to make the required payload = https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/catalog-batch/reference/

I tried generating new access tokens 2 or 3 times. I also tried changing the payload to check whether the documentation may be outdated but nothing helped me to solve this issue.

I am expecting that the product catalog batch API works, so that we can update the products from our side.

Comment: This type of question is better asked with FB support than here imho.

Comment: I tried the batch API through https://github.com/ignacio-chiazzo/ruby_whatsapp_sdk and works for me. What's the error you're getting?